# Need to copy dependency to specified folder

Tags: java, maven, build

Is it possible to make a copy of particular dependency and place it to required folder during maven build procedure? This dependencies is used in main project as well as in a small utility script, so they should be present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
[Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)
[Copy dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)